# SSIS Duplicate Entry for key PRIMARY

Tags: sql-server, mysql, ssis

I'm creating a simple Pipeline from a SQL Server Database to a MySQL Database, the issue is the pipeline won't work just once, but the more data is added to the first added should also be added in the destination database and here's where it gets hard.
I only want to add the new rows to the destination database... i tried but couldn't
any suggestions ?

Comment: Report specific facts. It's just useless to complain.

Comment: It's unfortunate, but [heterogeneous replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/heterogeneous-database-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) used to be more supported in the past, now it's deprecated, but in case you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar running in our environment. Here is how we did it.
You only have to worry about what you have sent from your SQL Server database. Create an SSIS package to load data into MYSQL, BUT you are going to be using a filter from a table that you create. The primary key is the last record sent.

The table should look like this.

Tablename | Key

Customer  101

Accounts  521

At the last step you need to insert into this table the max Primary key ID for the table you sent.

Then the next time the time the package run just filter the data being sent by the table. Example Select * FROM Customer where PK_ID > 101.
Just ensure your package has the correct error handling. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: It actually worked, but now I have another issue, I made sure everything is working and I executed the pipeline and left work, and now i'm really worried about leaving SSIS on debugging mode for the weekend... Is it alright? @perry147

Comment: Why are you executing it in debug mode?  Debug mode is for testing.   If it works and you have tested it thoroughly and it shows that it does not have any issue - deploy it.

Comment: But now I left it running, it probably ended by now but it's on debug mode.... Is it safe for the servers? Idk am new to this

Comment: I think you might have a larger issue here -  you need to get someone else to do this. By asking me (an internet guy) if something is safe for you server is very worrisome.  Hire someone. I understand you might have been forced into this role. and it is not your fault.

Comment: Excuse me I didn't get what you're saying. I'm simply asking if I kept an etl job running on debug mode woult it be a problem? It's my first job experience I'm still learning it's nothing like at the university

Comment: Is the id `AUTO_INCREMENT`?